# Converitr una cadena a un array de char sin espacios y sin letras repetidas con charAt en java

Tags: java, string, conversión-de-tipos

Me gustaría poder convertir un texto a un array de char sin que tuviera letras repetidas ni espacios en blanco usando charAt, y estoy un poco atascado. Si alguien pudiera ayudarme

Hasta ahora solo conseguí convertir a array de char el texto. Si se pudiera hacer en el momento en el que se insertan los char al array, vamos evitar que se pongan los char repetidos y los char que sean espacios. Todo en el momento de inserción. Se podría hacer esto ?

```
public char[] StringToArrayWithoutRepeat(String inputString) {

        int size = inputString.length();
        char[] arrayLetters = null;
         
        for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) { 
            if( inputString.charAt(i)!=' ' &&  inputString.charAt(i) != inputString.charAt(i+1)
                    && arrayLetters[i]!= inputString.charAt(i)) {
                arrayLetters[i] = inputString.charAt(i);
            } 
        }
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayLetters));
        return arrayLetters;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) { 

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        App app = new App();
        System.out.println("Introduzca el texto: ");
        String texto= sc.nextLine();
        app.StringToArray(texto);
    }
```

Comment: Solo estás mirando si la letra es diferente a la siguiente, no si está repetida. Te recomiendo que compares si la letra ya está en tu array de letras "distintas", es decir, en `arrayLetters`, en vez de `inputString.charAt(i) != inputString.charAt(i+1)`. Puedes crear un método nuevo que sea `boolean letraNoRepetida(char letra, char[] arrayLetras){}` y devolver true si la letra no está en el array, de esa manera podrás llamar al método en tu `if` y solo añadirá la letra al array si aun no está en él :) Por cierto, te faltó inicializar `arrayletters`, ya que lo declaras a `null` y dará error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenía un ratito así que he intentado hacer una respuesta lo más explicada posible. Todos los cambios que hice así como sus explicaciones están en los comentarios del código, pero en resumen, *solo necesitabas cambiar una de tus comparaciones en ese `if` dentro del bucle* y ya lo tenías!

```
public class CuantasLetrasDeCada {

    public char[] StringToArrayWithoutRepeat(String inputString) {

        int size = inputString.length();
        /* Este null aquí provocará un NullPointerException más adelante
         *así que mejor instanciar el array*/
//        char[] arrayLetters = null;
        char[] arrayLetters = new char[size];

        /*En vez de trabajar con inputString, trabajaremos con stringEnMinusculas, así no tendremos
        * que preocuparnos de si la letra que tenemos es una 'E' o una 'e' */
        String stringEnMinusculas = inputString.toLowerCase();

        for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
            /* Aquí el i+1 provocará que nos salgamos de rango y nos dará un index out of range, por qué?
             * Pues porque cuando estés mirando la última letra, intentarás mirar la siguiente tamibén!
             * Vamos a comentar este if entero y añadir uno mejor abajo, pero manteniendo la primera
             * condición, puesto que eso es lo que evitará los espacios!*/
//            if( inputString.charAt(i)!=' ' &&  inputString.charAt(i) != inputString.charAt(i+1)
//                    && arrayLetters[i]!= inputString.charAt(i)) {
//                arrayLetters[i] = inputString.charAt(i);
//            }
            /* Para la segunda condición, tal como te indiqué en el comentario, vamos a usar el resultado
             *  de un método que crearé abajo de este, así no tenemos que escribir tanto en el if, y quedará
             * el código más fácil de leer. Como parámetros le pasamos la letra actual, y nuestro array
             * de letras "sin repetir" */
            if( stringEnMinusculas.charAt(i) != ' ' && !letraEnArray(stringEnMinusculas.charAt(i), arrayLetters)){
                //Esto se queda igual que estaba
                arrayLetters[i] = stringEnMinusculas.charAt(i);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayLetters));
        return arrayLetters;
    }

    private boolean letraEnArray(char letra, char[] arrayDeLetrasSinRepetir){
        // Primero declaramos que la letra NO existe
        boolean letraEnArray = false;
        // Ahora hacemos un bucle para recorrer el array de letras que fuimos guardando
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayDeLetrasSinRepetir.length; i++) {
            /* Si encontramos la letra, letraEnArray pasa a ser true y además
             *usamos break para que no siga ejecutándose, puesto que ya nos da igual lo demás*/
            if(letra == arrayDeLetrasSinRepetir[i]){
                letraEnArray = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // Devolvemos el booleano
        return letraEnArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "Esto es una frase con algunas letras repetidas";

        CuantasLetrasDeCada instance = new CuantasLetrasDeCada();
        //Ahora veamos el resultado!
        System.out.println(instance.StringToArrayWithoutRepeat(test));
        /* Vaya... imprime algo un poco extraño, no? -> esto    una fr    c    lg              p  id  
         Por qué hay tantos espacios en blanco?? Pues porque estamos usando la misma variable
         para recorrer el input que para almacenar las letras! Vamos a solucionarlo con
         una versión un poco mejorada (pero sencillita) de tu método StringToArrayWithoutRepeat()*/
        System.out.println(instance.StringToArrayWithoutRepeat(test));
        System.out.println("Ahora imprimiremos la versión mejorada del método:");
        System.out.println(instance.StringToArrayWithoutRepeatV2(test));
        /* Ahora el resultado es -> estounafrclgpid                               
         * Eso está genial, tenemos todas las letras juntas y los espacios están al final!
         * Se podrían eliminar con un .trim() a continuación del string, eso borrará
         * los espacios sobrantes del string.*/
    }

    public char[] StringToArrayWithoutRepeatV2(String inputString) {
        // Aquí he borrado todos los comentarios y solo dejaré los de los cambios nuevos
        int size = inputString.length();
        char[] arrayLetters = new char[size];
        // Creo una nueva variable que servirá para llevar la cuenta de las letras que guardamos
        int letrasInsertadas = 0;
        String stringEnMinusculas = inputString.toLowerCase();

        for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
            if( stringEnMinusculas.charAt(i) != ' ' && !letraEnArray(stringEnMinusculas.charAt(i), arrayLetters)){
                /* En vez de guardarlo en arrayLetters[i], usamos nuestro nuevo contador,
                 * al añadir el ++ al final lo que hacemos es que tras ejecutarse esa línea
                 * la variable se incremente automaticamente en 1! De esa manera está lista
                 * para la siguiente letra que encontremos */
                arrayLetters[letrasInsertadas++] = stringEnMinusculas.charAt(i);
            }
        }
        return arrayLetters;
    }

}
```

---

He llamado a la clase de diferente manera, y para no andar escribiendo la entrada de cada vez he usado un string *hardcodeado* pero podrás adaptarlo fácilmente a tu código puesto que es casi casi lo mismo que tenías tú.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta y tu tiempo, me has ayudado bastante a entender ciertos conceptos.